# how to use printf when printing a value from vector<string>?

Tags: c++, c++11

I wanted to print the value of string type in a vector using printf but it crashes when i run the program. Please help.

```
vector<string> vec{"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
printf("%s\n",vec[1]);
```

Comment: `printf("%s\n",vec[1].c_str());`

Comment: `printf` knows nothing about `std::string`.  Why do you want to use `printf` instead of `std::cout`?

Comment: "Doctor it hurts when I use `printf`." "So don't use `printf`!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` expects a `char*` pointer, not a `std::string` object.  You can use the `std::string::c_str()` method to get a suitable pointer for `%s` to use:

```cpp
printf("%s\n", vec[1].c_str());
```